# Oauth 2.0 vs Auth0 vs WSO2

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, auth0

What is the difference between oauth 2.0, auth0 and wso2? I saw some related post where are explained, more or less well, what are the differences between oauth 2.0 and auth0 but ws02 is not included in the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth 2.0 is a widely used specification for authorization aspects of resources: https://oauth.net/2/

Auth0 and WSO2 Identity Server are two identity providers (IAM solutions). Both support OAuth 2.0.

Auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/protocol-oauth2

WSO2 IS: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/working-with-oauth/

Comment: Okay, so if you use auth0 you don't use wso2 and viceversa, isn't it?